# Trying to open a Word doc from my app in Xoom(Android 3.0), but getting "Unknown Source"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a word document(also later I would be building a pdf too, but right now word document is to be opned) in my folder "/mnt/sdcard/Download/baby_details.doc" and the application type I set to open this document is "application/msword".

In my eclipse LogCat I was watching how a Word document is opened by the native android activity and I get to see the result as

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/per-general-business-letter.doc typ=application/msword flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.qo.android.moto/com.qo.android.quickoffice.QuickofficeDispatcher } from pid 24132
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/per-general-business-letter.doc typ=application/msword flg=0x1 cmp=com.qo.android.moto/com.qo.android.quickword.Quickword } from pid 1591
Start proc com.qo.android.moto:Quickword for activity com.qo.android.moto/com.qo.android.quickword.Quickword: pid=2452 uid=10010 gids={3003}
```

so I tried to open the doc with

```
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("dat", "/mnt/sdcard/Download/baby_details.doc");
                bundle.putString("typ", "application/msword");
                Intent docClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                docClient.putExtras(bundle);
                docClient.setClassName("com.qo.android.moto", "com.qo.android.quickword.Quickword");
                startActivityForResult(docClient, WORD_APP);
```

but I get a Unknown Source, I also tried changing the setClassName to

```
docClient.setClassName("com.qo.android.moto", "com.qo.android.quickoffice.QuickofficeDispatcher");
```

and still get the same error.

I would like to know if anyone has used the native QuickOffice activity to open a word/pdf/xls?

Thanks,
Sana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put "dat" and "type" in a bundle; use `Intent.setType` and `intent.setData` (or just use [`intent.setDataAndType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29). And make sure the URI you use for the data matches what the system expects (`file://`).

Comment: And don't hardcode '/mnt/sdcard', use the android.os.Environment class for the correct path to the external storage.